# How to make an animation similar to "Slide to unlock" within a UIView Like Swipable TabbleView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode6, xib

In my Xib. I have included 3 sub views and 3 small imageviews

[image]

![I Have to include animation to right swipe and left swipe for each view separately. Simple swipe for one view works fine according to the direction of swipe the item gets Favorited and the image position also could change ][2]

```
 //........towards right Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];

    //........towards left Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSLog(@"Right Gesture");
    self.Favimage.hidden = false;
    self.closeImage.hidden = true;


}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSLog(@"Left Gesture");
    self.Favimage.hidden = true;
    self.closeImage.hidden = false;


}
```

This what im tried now. I have to do it with better animation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `UISlider` it have all you need.

Comment: @cy-4AH sorry idon't think so. i have to anmate the view when i swipe right or left. if i swipe right. the close sign get hidden , favorite get visible and last only one shoe and one tick mark shoed get visible. U have any idea to implement this thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think. This is what you are looking for

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSLog(@"Right Gesture");
    self.closeImage.hidden = true;
   // self.shoe.hidden = true;
    //Do moving

    CGRect finalFrame = CGRectMake(150,5, 64, 63);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _shoe.frame = finalFrame;
         self.Favimage.hidden = true;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.Favimage.hidden = false;

      // [_Favimage removeFromSuperview];

        //[_Favimage removeFromSuperview];
        //[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    }];
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSLog(@"Left Gesture");
    self.Favimage.hidden = true;
    self.closeImage.hidden = false;

    CGRect finalFrame = CGRectMake(77,5, 70, 63);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _shoe.frame = finalFrame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //self.Favimage.hidden = false;

        //[_Favimage removeFromSuperview];

        //[_Favimage removeFromSuperview];
        //[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    }];
    // do moving
}
```

try this one